# OpenCart PayPal payment

Tags: paypal, opencart

I've stuck with PayPal Standard payment for OpenCart and found no solution yet.

What I've done:

- Created a business account on sandbox.paypal.com
- Set up following web preferences:

  - Auto return (URL specified)
  - PDT enabled
- Enabled IPN (URL specified: http://my.domain.com/index.php?route=payment/pp_standard/callback
- Created personal account on sandbox.paypal.com
- Set up PayPal Standard extension in OpenCart:

  - Specified e-mail of the business account created above
  - Specified PDT token
  - Specified Sandbox mode
  - Transaction method - Sale

When I try to pay with PayPal I'm redirected to PayPal and pay proper amount. Then I'm automatically redirected back to my site by URL specified in PayPal business account's settings. So this tells me the payment recipient is recognized by PayPal.

At this point joy ends. In the sending account's activity log I see sending transactions. All of them have status *Unclaimed*. In the business account's log I see no transactions. In the IPN history I see no IPNs and in the web server's log I see no requests to /index.php?route=payment/pp_standard/callback.

I'm certainly missing something. But I can't figure - what.

Answer (score 1):

In Paypal checkout section in open cart admin panel, go to the general tab of that, you will find `test mode` option, set it yes. and for `debugging mode` set it yes. Check your checkout process now. i think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue a while back. For me, it was because the payments being sent to OpenCart were in a different currency to what was held in the Sandbox balance. E.g. OpenCart was sending orders in GBP but the Sandbox holds currency in USD.

I fixed by changing a setting in the Sandbox account.

**Profile > My Settings > Block Payments > Click Update**

On the page which appears, there is an option "Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold:". I just set that to **Yes**.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a case. I've set "Yes".
Moreover I've sent Euro, which is a primary currency in recipient's account. 
Also I tried to send money directly on PayPal (all is in sandbox) with same result. 

So it seems to be a problem with recipient's account and has nothing to do with OpenCart at all